# Using itertools.product and want to seed a value

Tags: python, image, download, seed, python-itertools

So I've wrote a small script to download pictures from a website.  It goes through a 7 alpha charactor value, where the first char is always a number.  The problem is if I want to stop the script and start it up again I have to start all over.

Can I seed itertools.product somehow with the last value I got so I don't have to go through them all again.

Thanks for any input.

here is part of the code:

```
numbers = '0123456789'
alnum = numbers + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

len7 = itertools.product(numbers, alnum, alnum, alnum, alnum, alnum, alnum) # length 7

for p in itertools.chain(len7):
    currentid = ''.join(p) 

    #semi static vars
    url = 'http://mysite.com/images/'
    url += currentid

    #Need to get the real url cause the redirect
    print "Trying " + url
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    res = openaurl(req)
    if res == "continue": continue
    finalurl = res.geturl()

    #ok we have the full url now time to if it is real
    try: file = urllib2.urlopen(finalurl)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.code

    im = cStringIO.StringIO(file.read())
    img = Image.open(im)
    writeimage(img)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you can write it as  `product(numbers, *[alnum] * 6)`, and you could use `string.digits` instead of `numbers` and `string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits` instead of `alnum`.

Comment: Nice, thank you.  Still trying to become familiar with Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a solution based on pypy's library code (thanks to agf's suggestion in the comments).

the state is available via the `.state` attribute and can be reset via `.goto(state)` where `state` is an index into the sequence (starting at 0).  there's a demo at the end (you need to scroll down, i'm afraid).

this is way faster than discarding values.

```
> cat prod.py 

class product(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        if len(kw) > 1:
            raise TypeError("product() takes at most 1 argument (%d given)" %
                             len(kw))
        self.repeat = kw.get('repeat', 1)
        self.gears = [x for x in args] * self.repeat
        self.num_gears = len(self.gears)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        # initialization of indicies to loop over
        self.indicies = [(0, len(self.gears[x]))
                         for x in range(0, self.num_gears)]
        self.cont = True
        self.state = 0

    def goto(self, n):
        self.reset()
        self.state = n
        x = self.num_gears
        while n > 0 and x > 0:
            x -= 1
            n, m = divmod(n, len(self.gears[x]))
            self.indicies[x] = (m, self.indicies[x][1])
        if n > 0:
            self.reset()
            raise ValueError("state exceeded")

    def roll_gears(self):
        # Starting from the end of the gear indicies work to the front
        # incrementing the gear until the limit is reached. When the limit
        # is reached carry operation to the next gear
        self.state += 1
        should_carry = True
        for n in range(0, self.num_gears):
            nth_gear = self.num_gears - n - 1
            if should_carry:
                count, lim = self.indicies[nth_gear]
                count += 1
                if count == lim and nth_gear == 0:
                    self.cont = False
                if count == lim:
                    should_carry = True
                    count = 0
                else:
                    should_carry = False
                self.indicies[nth_gear] = (count, lim)
            else:
                break

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if not self.cont:
            raise StopIteration
        l = []
        for x in range(0, self.num_gears):
            index, limit = self.indicies[x]
            l.append(self.gears[x][index])
        self.roll_gears()
        return tuple(l)

p = product('abc', '12')
print list(p)
p.reset()
print list(p)
p.goto(2)
print list(p)
p.goto(4)
print list(p)
> python prod.py 
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2')]
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2')]
[('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2')]
[('c', '1'), ('c', '2')]
```

you should test it more - i may have made a dumb mistake - but the idea is quite simple, so you should be able to fix it :o)  you're free to use my changes; no idea what the original pypy licence is.

also `state` isn't really the full state - it doesn't include the original arguments - it's just an index into the sequence.  maybe it would have been better to call it index, but there are already indici[sic]es in the code...

**update**

here's a simpler version that is the same idea but works by transforming a sequence of numbers.  so you just `imap` it over `count(n)` to get the sequence offset by `n`.

```
> cat prod2.py 

from itertools import count, imap

def make_product(*values):
    def fold((n, l), v):
        (n, m) = divmod(n, len(v))
        return (n, l + [v[m]])
    def product(n):
        (n, l) = reduce(fold, values, (n, []))
        if n > 0: raise StopIteration
        return tuple(l)
    return product

print list(imap(make_product(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]), count()))
print list(imap(make_product(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]), count(3)))

def product_from(n, *values):
    return imap(make_product(*values), count(n))

print list(product_from(4, ['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]))

> python prod2.py 
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
[('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

(the downside here is that if you want to stop and restart you need to have kept track yourself of how many you have used)

Comment: This looks great so far.  However I can't figure out how the class is working.  Any trying to print something with 103 octillion combinations takes a while ;)  It brings up the next problem of computing the index now.

Comment: the program works like the mileometer in a car.  each call to roll_gears moves the end (left-most in this case, but right-most in a mileometer) number one.  if that ticks over to 0 then it moves the next number up one, etc etc.

Comment: Makes sense. And its is now working!!!  Had to add code for base 36 math.  Thank you and thanks you to agf for pointing out PyPy

Comment: This is cool. If you combine it with my answer, then `goto` could take a state, calculate the offset (assuming no duplicate values within an input sequence), and then move to that state.

Comment: i just posted a simpler version (see "update") that might be easier to understand/adapt.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a fair way along the iterator, it's going to take a while to get to the spot using dropwhile.

You probably should adapt a recipe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534085/174728) so that you can save the state with a pickle between runs.

Make sure that your script can only run once at a time, or you will need something more elaborate, such as a server process that hands out the ids to the scripts

Comment: Or something like the [PyPy implementation](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/2a83c08dcb0e/lib_pypy/itertools.py#cl-434) would be faster, pickleable, and you could probably even figure out how to skip it forward to a starting value much more quickly than with `dropwhile`.

Comment: @agf, using version from pypy is a great idea

Comment: I came up with something that should be faster than `dropwhile` for `itertools.product` if none of the input sequences have any duplicate values.

Comment: Look however its beyond me how I can actually use this.

Answer (score 1):

If your input sequences don't have any duplicate values, this may be faster than `dropwhile` to advance `product` as it doesn't require you to compare all of the dropped values by calculating the correct point to resume iteration.

```
from itertools import product, islice
from operator import mul

def resume_product(state, *sequences):
    start = 0
    seqlens = map(len, sequences)
    if any(len(set(seq)) != seqlen for seq, seqlen in zip(sequences, seqlens)):
        raise ValueError("One of your sequences contains duplicate values")
    current = end = reduce(mul, seqlens)
    for i, seq, seqlen in zip(state, sequences, seqlens):
        current /= seqlen
        start += seq.index(i) * current
    return islice(product(*sequences), start + 1, end)


seqs = '01', '23', '45', '678'        

# if I want to resume after '1247':
for i in resume_product('1247', *seqs):
    # blah blah
    pass
```