# Python Brute Force Password Resume Capability

Tags: python, passwords

Recently, I started coding a simple python Brute Forcer for web forms and so far so good.

But, i want my bruteforcer to be capable of stopping a brute force operation and resume later with the previous session.

To do this i want to keep the last password tested and enter it sometime later, that's not the problem.
My problem is that i don't know how to start bruteforcing from a specific word.

As an example, when i enter the word "Orange",
i want the program to continue testing:
Orangf, 
Orangg,
Orangh and so on..

So far i'm using this code to do a simple bruteforce with the charset `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`
and length 6 characters.

```
for word in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', repeat=6)):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that this question contains part of the answer to yours:
[Using itertools.product and want to seed a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864809/using-itertools-product-and-want-to-seed-a-value)

Comment: This seems promising, wait a little for me to test it.

Comment: Ok, i tested it and it's close to what i want, it just needs a little modification to produce the words as i want it, i will post back my results in a few minutes.

Comment: so far i have this : http://pastebin.com/xCt9a2Ax
and my output is: aa
ba
ca
ab
bb
cb
ac
bc
cc

Comment: Ok, i got it working the way i want. Thanks for pointing me to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all the possibilities generated by `itertools.imap`, create a list of all those possibilities, and iterate through that, keeping track of where you are in the list.

When you pause, record the list index that you were at last, and when you resume, you can continue at that list index again.

**Edit:** Oops, brain fart. That's definitely not a good idea -- see comments.

Comment: I don't think creating a list of all possibilities is a good idea since the list would be too large.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought this too, but i think it's not handy for my program because later i will have to enter the last values of the loops that i was keeping track. Something like: 356,235,576,757.. Although it's good for my purpose, i want to enter just a single word to resume. I have seen some closed-source bruteforcers in the past that did that.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Doesn't `imap` give you back an iterator, though? Could you store that in a variable and just use `next()` repeatedly?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to enter a word to start from, not necessarily start and stop like I thought you meant. So that doesn't work either. It looks to me like sgillis is on the right track though.

Comment: Well, what I was thinking of is slightly different from what you want, I think. But you could store the result of `imap` in a variable, say, `possibilities.` You can get a password to try by calling `possibilities.next()`, and keep doing that until you either reach the last possibility or you send the program some sort of signal to pause. And you'd resume not by entering the word that you want to continue from, but by just calling `possibilities.next()` some more.

Comment: Well, i'm new to python and these things are new to me, could you please give me an example of what you mean?